# Validating user input in Laravel using the Validator

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I'm trying to use the RegisterController in Laravel, but I can't get the Validator to work. I don't understand what the problem is, because it should just take an array and validate it.

When I try to send a JSON with the right fields to the register route, I get this error:

```
BadMethodCallException: Method validate does not exist. in file /home/deb85528n3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Macroable.php on line 96
```

Below is my code:

```
protected function validator(array $data)
{       
    $validator = Validator::make($data,
        [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'birth_year' => 'required|integer',
        'lat' => 'required',
        'lon' => 'required',
        ]);

    echo $validator->errors();

   if ($validator->fails())
   {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
   }

   if ($validator->passes())
   {
        $response = "validator passed";
        return response()->json($response);
   }

}
```

I also tried using the Validator in a different way:

```
public function validator(Request $request){
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'birth_year' => 'required|integer|min:4',
        'lat' => 'required|numeric',
        'lon' => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
}
```

But then I get this error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::validator() must be an instance of App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Request, array given, called in /home/deb85528n3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 31 in file /home/deb85528n3/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php on line 103
```

Edited to include the whole RegisterController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/home';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name'  => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'      => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'   => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'birth_year' => 'required|integer|min:4',
        'lat'        => 'required|numeric',
        'lon'        => 'required|numeric',
    ]);


    echo $validator->errors();

   if ($validator->fails())
   {
        return response()->json(['errors'=>$validator->errors()]);
    }

    if ($validator->passes())
    {
        $response = "validator passed";
        return response()->json($response);
    }
}


/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    //maybe check if facebook login here?
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        'birth_year' => $data['birth_year'],
        'lat' => $data['lat'],
        'lon' => $data['lon'],
    ]);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you post your whole class? Or the imports at the top (it sounds like you should have `use Illuminate\Http\Request;` at the top but that might not be the whole issue. This is referring to your second example)

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(),` is throwing an error, because `$request->all()` returns an array. This is logical. Just give it the request as parameter. The first one I don't understand.

Comment: I updated the question with the whole class

Comment: I'm using Laravel 5.5.24

Comment: from where you are calling function `validate()` in RegisterController  ?

Comment: I don't know from where it's being called. When I go to the /register route it calls that function, but I cannot find the code. After validation is correct it also runs the create() function, and I have no idea where the code responsible for this resides

Answer (score 0):

The `register` method calls the `validator` method and passes through an array, it then expects that an instance of `\Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator` to be returned.

Unless you're needed to override the default responses for registering a user, you should just be able to have:

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'last_name'  => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email'      => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password'   => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        'birth_year' => 'required|integer|min:4',
        'lat'        => 'required|numeric',
        'lon'        => 'required|numeric',
    ]);
}
```

Comment: I now get the error Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to a member function validate() on null in file /home/deb85528n3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php on line 31

Comment: @kajdehoop Please can you post your entire `RegisterController`? Also what version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I've posted the entire RegisterController. I'm using Laravel 5.5.24

Comment: @kajdehoop My bad, I'd forgot to return the validator. The above code should work for you.

Comment: It now works when the validation passes (: But when it fails, it doesn't return an error. I'd like to have a JSON response with the fields that didn't pass the validation

Comment: @kajdehoop Can you show your JS code for making the json request? Laravel should automatically convert the response for you so I'm thinking the issue might be with your JS.

Answer (score 0):

change your function name

```
use Validator;
```

add this in your controller,

remove this

```
public function validator(Request $request){
```

Write your validation rules in model like below

```
 public static function rules()
    {
       return [
         'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
         'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
         'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
         'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
         'birth_year' => 'required|integer|min:4',
         'lat' => 'required|numeric',
         'lon' => 'required|numeric',
       ];
     }
```

and call this rule in your controller

```
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), "Your model Name"::rules()); 
  if ($validator->fails()) {
        //throw exception
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by the 'model name'? For registering new users, should I put this in the User model?

Comment: Yeah you can write that in User model